# How to make Asynctask wait untill GCM Broadcast is received

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

I am using below code to register my device for GCM

```
private class GetGcmRegId extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pdia.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pdia.setCancelable(false);
        pdia.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pdia.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(LoginActivity.this, Utility.SENDER_ID);
        regid = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(LoginActivity.this);
        return regid;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pdia.dismiss();
        regid = result;
        System.out.println("regid ==========>"+regid);
    }
}
```

Now, one thing I know is that I will get register id via a Broadcast. But how can I make this asynctask wait until the broadcast is received?

Currently, this code `System.out.println("regid ==========>"+regid);`
prints nothing, but when I run the activity second time, I am receiving the register id;

Comment: Why would you let it wait? Much better to start a new one with the rest of the task when you get the gcm.

Comment: can you please explain more

Comment: 'I will get register id via a Broadcast.'. Is that true? Then what does ' regid = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(LoginActivity.this);'. It looks as if you just get the regid there. And that is what you are printing.

Comment: but it is returning me null when i run for the first time. when i receive the broadcast only then it is returning me the register id for gcm. but for that I need to run the activity again

Comment: Thinking about it again i see no reason at all to wait in the asynctask. Because what would you do further there having received it? If you have a broadcast receiver you can do what you want after you got the gcm. So explain why you want to wait there as i think it is not necessary.

Comment: 'but it is returning me null when i run for the first time.'. Of course because you are to quick with that statement as you did not yet receive the gcm. Remove that statement from the asynctask and put it in the onReceive of the broadcast receiver. Because there you get the gcm.

Comment: Scene is like this I am registering device from the call above this is in my activity A, now I want to wait untill device is registered so that i can send that register Id to my server from next activity and store it for further use

Comment: Have you fixed your problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't have to wait. Refer to my following sample code. Hope this helps!

Firstly, I check SharedPreferences, if empty, get token (device registration id) from Google server. Token will be stored in SharedPreferences for other use / providing to server-side app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Context mContext = this;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    SharedPreferences appPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("com.example.gcmclient_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String token = appPrefs.getString("token", "");
    if (token.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            getGCMToken("0123456789"); // Project ID: xxxx Project Number: 0123456789 at https://console.developers.google.com/project/...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
}
...

private void getGCMToken(final String senderId) throws Exception {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = "";
            try {
                InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(mContext);
                token = instanceID.getToken(senderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
                    SharedPreferences appPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("com.example.gcmclient_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appPrefs.edit();
                    prefsEditor.putString("token", token);
                    prefsEditor.commit();
                }
                Log.i("GCM_Token", token);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
            return null;            
        }           
    }.execute();
}   
}
```