# Cannot get a registrationID from GCM

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

Despite all tries and reviewing previous questions and solutions on SO, I cannot manage to get a registrationID from GCM.

I am using the [pushplugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), and trying to build for Android using Cordova. App is successfully built but it seems the onNotificationGCM functions in the are never being called. Success handler is called. I use Genymotion Android simulator.

On github issues some say to attach the onNotification functions to window object. But I could not make this work too. Is there a general problem. Anybody using this plugin successfully?

What can be the reason for that?
The trial here uses another cordova plugin different than the mentioned one above. Although I have tried the example in the above plugin's github repo, it did not work.

index.js:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    // "senderID":"273794328096"
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
            alert("Register called");
            window.GcmPushPlugin.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler, {
                "senderId":"273794328096",
                "jsCallback":"onNotificationGCM"
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Register called");
            pushNotification.register(this.successHandler,this.errorHandler,{"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});
        }
    },
    // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
    successHandler: function(result) {
        alert('Callback Success! Result = '+ result.gcm)
    },
    errorHandler:function(error) {
        alert("Error:" + error);
    },
};

function onNotificationGCM(notification) {
  console.log("Event Received: " + notification); // { "extra": {"url" : "someurl.js" } } 
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Suggest that you try a GCM client sample code from GitHub

Comment: I have tried three of them. but they do not work.

Comment: @Huey added relevant code now.

Comment: Cannot understand why downvote. Is it as if there are some persons just downvote passing by. Anyway it's a beautiful life.

Comment: You can refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110963/how-to-make-asynctask-wait-untill-gcm-broadcast-is-received/32111549#32111549). If it works for you, I'll add as answer at this question.

Comment: @BNK Sorry but my codebase is JavaScript on Cordova 5.x platform, not Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code

```
var Project = {};

var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        app.registerDevice();
    },

    registerDevice: function(){
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.platformId=='android'){
            try{
                var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                pushNotification.register(
                    app.successPN,
                    app.errorPN,
                    {
                        "senderID": "727700427600",
                        "ecb": "Project.Notification"
                    }
                );
            }
            catch (ex){
                // window.alert('Error (message): ' + ex.message);
                // window.alert('Error (stack): ' + ex.stack);
            }
            console.log("regID = " + localStorage['pioneer.device.regid']);
        }
    },
    successPN: function (result){
        // window.alert('PN Success: ' + result);
    },
    errorPN: function (result){
        // window.alert('PN Error: ' + result);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

**Project.Notification**

```
Project.Notification = function(e){
    // Pioneer.alert(JSON.stringify(e), 'alert');
    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
            // process reg id
            break;                
        case 'message':
            // print message
            break;
        case 'error':
            // window.alert("Notification error: " + e.msg);
            break;
        default:
            // window.alert("Notification - Unknown event");
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: No way. It is not working. ı only see the output alert of the sucessPN saying OK. Also to clear I have put some alerts in Project.Notification cases: for each like:

     `window.alert("registerId: " + e.regid + " " + e.event.regid);
            window.alert("Notification message: " + " " + e + " " + e.message + " " + e.event.message);
             window.alert("Notification error: " + e.msg);
             window.alert("Notification - Unknown event");`

Comment: Problem solved! I am now testing app on the real Android device rather than simulator.